# How to Remove Trailing Zeros in XPath?

Tags: xpath

I have some not very clean 3rd party data that included numbers like:

```
PRICE
118.0000
99.0000
etc etc
```

normally would just use:

```
{price[1]}
```

but I just get price like $18,000,000.00 where it should be $118

I tried this (just guessing) ...

```
number{('price[1]')}
```

but nothing showed up for the price.

I also tried

```
format-number{(., 'price[1]')}
```

but that did not work.

Then I read I can use

```
translate(@Price, ',.', '.')
```

I tried that as

```
translate(@price, ',.', '.')
```

but no price showed

I then tried several variations using the [1] part , I'm only guessing as I'm not really a coder:

```
{translate(@price[1], ',.', '.')}

{translate(@price[1],',.','.')} ( I clean the spaces out)
```

then this one

```
translate(@price[1], ',.', '.')
```

and it finally showed a price but only as $1.00 where it should have been $1055 or another one should have been $1145 but they all showed $1.00

What can I do, it must be all on one line as it goes in my web based form to be submitted to import the data?

UPDATED:

Here is what I tried to write in the comments:

I tried these below and this is the results.I used your exact examples including the price as in the first 2 examples, then I tried with the "price" code but that is producing a $1 price again.

```
 substring-before(118.00, '.') $11,800.00
 substring-before('118.00','.')$11,800.00
 substring-before('price[1]','.')$1.00
 substring-before(price[1], '.')$1.00
```

I also tried using the brackets as I would normaly but that produces no price...

```
  {substring-before(price[1], '.')}
 {substring-before('price[1]','.')}
 {substring-before('118.00','.')}
 {substring-before(118.00, '.')}
```

I have tried to upload a much smaller copy of some of the input document and just changed some private details with "privatedomain" but I have no permission to include the links so they were deleted.

```
PROGRAMNAME PROGRAMURL  CATALOGNAME LASTUPDATED NAME    KEYWORDS    DESCRIPTION SKU MANUFACTURER    MANUFACTURERID  UPC ISBN    CURRENCY    SALEPRICE   PRICE   RETAILPRICE FROMPRICE   BUYURL  IMPRESSIONURL   IMAGEURL    ADVERTISERCATEGORY  THIRDPARTYID    THIRDPARTYCATEGORY  AUTHOR  ARTIST  TITLE   PUBLISHER   LABEL   FORMAT  SPECIAL GIFT    PROMOTIONALTEXT STARTDATE   ENDDATE OFFLINE ONLINE  INSTOCK CONDITION   WARRANTY    STANDARDSHIPPINGCOST
```

PrivateName (deleted link)  PrivateName - Product Catalog   2015-03-21 23:06:21.558 Ainsley Cuff, Gold  $100-$299, cuff, gold, Open Cuff    Captivatingly colorful, Kendra Scott’s collection will spruce up a basic sweater and can simultaneously fancy up a dressier cocktail frock. Her pieces have a southern influence, which brings fun, festivity, and charm to the collection’s aesthetic.         14k Gold Plated  2 Inches Wide  Malleable  kens-00005B Kendra Scott                USD     120.0000            (deleted link)  (deleted link)/jpeg_1.jpg   Bracelets       All Jewelry ,Designers,Shop All,All Jewelry,A-Z Designers,Shop by Occasion,Best of PrivateName,Kendra Scott,Office,Everyday,Vacation,Classic,Casual,Byzantine,Black and White,Gold,Cuff,Destination: Morocco,Back in Stock,Kendra Scott,Bracelets                                                       yes
PrivateName (deleted link)  PrivateName - Product Catalog   2015-03-21 23:06:21.559 Crystal Deco Brooch $100-$299, crystal  "Part of the Ben-Amun Evening Collection.       Antique silver-plated over brass  Clear Swarovski crystals   Length 2.5""        NOTES:  This product is made-to-order. Please allow up to 2-3 weeks for delivery. Expedited shipping is not available."  BAMU-00037P Ben-Amun Bridal             USD     195.0000            (deleted link)  (deleted link)/jpg_2.jpg    Brooches        Collections,Shop By,Designers,Brooches,All Jewelry,Bridal,A-Z Designers,Jewelry Trends,Evening,Bridal,Deco,Crystal,Estate,Ben-Amun Bridal,Shop All                                                      yes
PrivateName (deleted link)  PrivateName - Product Catalog   2015-03-21 23:06:21.559 Gold Teardrop Cutout Earrings   $0-$100, gold   "Wendy Mink’s jewelry mixes aspects of traditional Eastern jewelry with classic European design principles. Her pieces are carefully handmade with simple yet unexpected combinations of colors, materials, and shapes. Her collection draws inspiration from textiles created by women in India, Nepal, and Tibet—three regions she spent a great deal of time in while holding a position at the World Bank prior to reinventing herself as a jewelry designer.           Gold-plated, 18kt  Length 2.5""  Width 1.75""  French wire hook         NOTES:  This item is made to order and may take up to 3 weeks for delivery."    wndm-00107E Wendy Mink              USD     73.0000

Please let me know if you need anything else:

Comment: From where are you calling XPath?   `format-number()` is an XSLT function, not an XPath (1.0 or 2.0) function.

Comment: What language is this, `number{('price[1]')}`? `{}` instead of `()`.. and `price[1]` enclosed within single quotes. Probably you should try `number(price[1])`

Comment: hi, yes sorry it probably is XSLT in XML. I'm using this plugin in wordpress to import data http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/ -  I just tried number(price[1])  but that also just shows the price as $1.00 and I also tried {number(price[1])} but that resulted in no prices showing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - we really need to see the input document.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XPATH 1.0 you might be able to use substring-before(xpath, expression)

```
substring-before(118.00, '.')
```

should give 118 if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: `substring-before` might indeed be an option, but its arguments are not `xpath` and `expression` - both arguments are strings (or evaluate to strings). That's why it really has to be `substring-before('118.00','.')`.

Comment: I tried these below and this is the results.I used your exact examples including the price as in the first 2 examples, then I tried with the "price" code but that is producing a $1 price again.

 substring-before(118.00, '.') $11,800.00
 substring-before('118.00','.')$11,800.00
 substring-before('price[1]','.')$1.00
 substring-before(price[1], '.')$1.00
 
 I also tried using the brackets as I would normaly but that produces no price...
  {substring-before(price[1], '.')}
 {substring-before('price[1]','.')}
 {substring-before('118.00','.')}
 {substring-before(118.00, '.')}

Comment: sorry I could not format the post to show a new line etc after each example

Comment: @user3308394 All of this is really no help at all - the only thing we need to see is the **input document** - and do not add new information in comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: I have changed my original post with more details after "UPDATED" I used the code option but as you can see it did not code the full document only the header.

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded the input document as requested a few days ago and I still have not had any response. Is there nothing that can be done to resolve this?